# Converting java language output to Joomla language output

Tags: java, php, joomla

in java if I run :

```
Locale.getDefault().toString()
```

I get **zh_tw**

I am sending this to a joomla site and setting the language like this:

```
$lang = &JFactory::getLanguage();
$lang->setLanguage( $_GET['lang'] );
$lang->load();
```

however the site requires the following format **zh-TW**

It appears that if it is not in that exact format the language will not change.  Is there a function somewhere in java or php that will convert the format for me?

I realise that I could write the method myself like this:

```
    public static String convertLanguageToJoomlaFormat(String lang) {
    String[] parts = lang.split("_");
    if(parts.length ==2)
        return parts[0]+"-"+parts[1].toUpperCase();
    return lang;
}
```

but am unsure if there are any cases where the format changes for particular languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Java API docs Locale.toString() is a:

> Getter for the programmatic name of
> the entire locale, with the language,
> country and variant separated by
> underbars. Language is always lower
> case, and country is always upper
> case. If the language is missing, the
> string will begin with an underbar. If
> both the language and country fields
> are missing, this function will return
> the empty string, even if the variant
> field is filled in (you can't have a
> locale with just a variant-- the
> variant must accompany a valid
> language or country code). Examples:
> "en", "de_DE", "_GB", "en_US_WIN",
> "de__POSIX", "fr__MAC"

Joomla 1.5 claims to use the IETF RFC3066 for locale names: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3066, but in reality it always uses the language and country code parts of the identifier like [en-GB].

The problem arise when the Java Locale does not have a country part. In this case you may use a 'hack' using the uppercase version of language code as the country code:

```
String[] tokens = locale.toString().split("_");
if (tokens.length >= 2 && tokens[1].length() == 2) {
    joomlaName = tokens[0]+"-"+tokens[1];
} else {
    joomlaName = tokens[0]+"-"+tokens[0].toUpperCase();
}
```